# Replacing $c$ With Infinity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, galilean-relativity

I am confused about replacing $c$ (the speed of light) with $\infty$. I just do not understand how this recovers the non-relativistic physics, mainly, how would this be demonstrated in the Lorentz Transformation? Would it affect simultaneity since infinity is now not defined along with time-dilation and length-contraction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a Lorentz boost along $x$. We have:
$$ \gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}\xrightarrow{c\to \infty} 1.$$
Then 
$$ \begin{array} & t' &= & \gamma \left(t-\frac{v}{c^2}\;x\right)&\xrightarrow{c\to \infty} & t \\
x' &= & \gamma \left(x-v\;t\right)&\xrightarrow{c\to \infty} & x - v\; t \\
y' &=& y \\
z' &=& z,
\end{array}$$
which is precisely a Galilean boost along $x$.

It is then easy to see that the rest of Lorentz transformations fall-back to Galilean boosts and rotations, thus recovering the non-relativistic transformation laws.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#From_group_postulates) calculation, of transformations between inertial reference frames from group postulates, ultimately finds a quantity $\kappa=-1/c^2$ that needs to be $\le0$, but what you're asking for is equivalent to setting $\kappa=0$. This special case obtains Galilean transformations; any other obtains Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 1):

The important factor in SR is 
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

When $c\to\infty$, $\gamma\to1$. So for what you mention in things such as time dilation ($\Delta t'=\gamma\Delta t$) or length contraction ($\gamma \Delta\ell'=\Delta\ell$), we end up with nothing different happening between inertial frames moving relative to each other. The same arguments can be made for the more general cases of [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), [relative velocities](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity%23Special_relativity&ved=2ahUKEwjrsM6amLHnAhWwmOAKHcMYCjIQygQwCXoECAUQBQ&usg=AOvVaw0m0SXEKYFMmpYdAc9no8vQ&cshid=1580588860900), etc.